# SOLR query boost

Tags: syntax, solr

I'm querying Solr like this:

```
http://XXX.xx.xx:xxx/solr/select?q=name:(pizza)&fq=locationid:6050 OR _query_:"{!bbox}"&sfield=location&pt=34.0211224, -118.39646&d=8
```

I am searching for records  on name  column and the record must fall on  8 kms Boundry OR locationid column value 6050.

Now I want to boost records which match locationid column value 6050.

Comment: Can you clean up this question please? It's difficult to understand what you are asking.  The abbreviations and lack of punctuation do not help, either. Put some effort into your question, and people will be more likely to put effort into their answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `locationid:6050` filter within the [filter query parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) it won't influence the score. You should first of all move your filter inside the `q` parameter. Then you can use the `edismax` or `dismax` query parser and play around with the weight of your filter like this: `locationid:6050^2`. Have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply .  If i move into q parameter it will search  for  6050 value in locationid column . i dont want it search .Its only a filter column